# Loop versus custom class

Tags: c#, for-loop

I am writing the where clause of a dynamic sql query with two 'column in (list)' style rules.

I can see this coming up several times with int ID pairs such as LocationID / ProductID or TransactionID / FeeID.

The following sample doesn't require a class placed outside the method and removes duplicates from the WHERE conditions:

```
  var x = (from DataRow row in expected.Rows
            select row.ItemArray[0]).Distinct().ToArray()
  var y = (from DataRow row in expected.Rows
            select row.ItemArray[1]).Distinct().ToArray();
  for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
  {
       com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@x" + i, int.Parse(TIDs[i].ToString()));
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < y.Length; i++)
  {
       com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@y" + i, int.Parse(ItemIDs[i].ToString()));
  }
```

is that preferable to this sample, which is less repetitive, or is there a better option?

```
  public class xy 
  {
    public int x;
    public int y;
  }
  var xy = (from DataRow row in expected.Rows
          select new xy()
          {
              x = int.Parse(row.ItemArray[0].ToString()),
              y = int.Parse(row.ItemArray[1].ToString())
          }).Distinct().ToArray();
  for (int i = 0; i < xy.Length; i++)
  {
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@x" + i, xy[i].x);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@y" + i, xy[i].y);
  }
```

Both would also require loop(s) for `querystring += "@x" + i + ", ";`

Comment: You could use the built in System.Drawing.Point structure instead of making your own class.

Comment: does that second one even compile?

Comment: @SamIam of course not the class and subsequent code aren't side by side in actual code; the representation is for brevity unless you were referring to a specific error?

Comment: Note that calling `Distinct` in the second query does nothing as `xy` is a class which uses reference equality by default, so all instances will be "distinct" regardless of their values of x and y.

Comment: @Fraser The way that you're using `Distinct()` also doesn't make very much sense.  in one place, you're calling it individually on `x` and `y`, and in the other, you're calling it on the combined `xy`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are different queries.  The first gets a distinct list of `X`s and a distinct list of `Y`s.  The second is *attempting* to get a distinct list of `X` and `Y` *combinations*.  However since `xy` is defined as a `class` and not a `struct` you will have multiple instances that have the same values of `x` and `y`.

If only getting distinct combinations is not a concern, you could avoid having to use a custom class (and avoid the reference equality issue) by using an anonymous type:

```
var xy = (from DataRow row in expected.Rows
          select new
          {
              x = int.Parse(row.ItemArray[0].ToString()),
              y = int.Parse(row.ItemArray[1].ToString())
          }).Distinct().ToArray();
  for (int i = 0; i < xy.Length; i++)
  {
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@x" + i, xy[i].x);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@y" + i, xy[i].y);
  }
```

You *might* get better performance with the second method since you're only enumerating the source list once, but unless that's a significant bottleneck it may not make a difference overall.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether `x` and `y` are related or not.

If they're not related, and you're just doing the same thing to them, then don't put them into a class.  You might consider putting duplicate code into a method if applicable, but don't just throw two random values into a class.

If they are related, such as if they're the x and y coordinates of a point, then you should put them into a class to represent your point.

---

In your case  it also looks like you might not even need to make a new class for them.  They're already in an array.

```
var xy = (from DataRow row in expected.Rows
      select row).Distinct().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the amount I ended up using the code, and the varying number of where clauses using an in operator I went

```
class SqlInHelper
{
    public static string AddTags (DataColumn col)
    {
        string colName = col.ColumnName;
        string addStr = "";
        int distinct = (from DataRow row in col.Table.Rows
                   select row[colName]).Distinct().Count();
        for(int i=0;i<distinct;i++)
        {
            addStr += "@" + colName + i + ", ";
        }

        return addStr.Substring(0, addStr.Length - 2); // remove last ", "
    }

    public static void AddParams(SqlCommand query, DataColumn col, out bool bValid)
    {
        string colName = col.ColumnName;
        var vals = (from DataRow row in col.Table.Rows
                        select row[colName]).Distinct().ToArray();
        if (query.CommandText.Contains("@" + colName + (vals.Length - 1))) {
            for (int i = 0; i < vals.Length; i++)
            {
                query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + colName + i, Convert.ChangeType(vals[i], col.DataType));
            }
            bValid = true;
        } else {
            bValid = false;
        }

    }
}
```

Stylistically I think this allows less repetition in code, faster queries (In operator has less comparisons to make), and is more understandable.